# Настроить Тоr на Proxy

Tags: сеть, proxy, tor

В общем ситуация такая. Есть сайт который на отрез не хочет работать если видит точку выхода Tor. Но при этом лезть через прокси, то всё хорошо. Проблема только в том, что прокси не анонимный. Можно как-то настроить чтоб ExitNode перебрасывалась на произвольный proxy

> Пользователь > Tor > Proxy > Сайт

Пробовал добавлять **HttpProxy** в **torrc** но он не появляется на выходе

Comment: Можно. Нужно обращаться через Tor к конечному прокси.

Comment: Это радует. Можно поподробней, что, где и как настроить

Comment: Настройку непонятно какого софта для работы через цепочку proxy предлагаете писать?

Comment: Tor Browser 6.0.8

Comment: по какому протоколу работает прокси?

Comment: Да прокси можно подобрать любой, SOCKS5, HTTPS, .... Лишь бы это не была выходная нода Тора, видимо сайт сверяет их со списком нод и блочит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем решил так.

Cтавим **proxychains**. В его настройках добавляем нужный прокси
**/etc/proxychains.conf**

```
#Отключаем рандом
#dynamic_chain
#random_chain
#chain_len = 2

#quiet_mode

#Всегда придерживаемся последовательности
strict_chain

proxy_dns 

tcp_read_time_out 15000
tcp_connect_time_out 80000

[ProxyList]
#Вначале будет идти трафик через Tor
socks5 127.0.0.1 9050
#Потом через выбранный нами прокси
socks5 178.150.96.58 45554
```

Если вдруг не будет работать по причине DNS
Можно также прописать DNS хардкорно

**/usr/lib/proxychains3/proxyresolv**

```
DNS_SERVER=77.109.138.45
```

И собственно сам запуск браузера через **proxychains**

```
proxychains chromium-browser
```

Если не расскомментировали **quiet_mode**, то в логах увидите что-то вроде

> S-chain|-<>-127.0.0.1:9050-<>-178.150.96.58:45554-<><>-172.217.17.195:443-<><>-OK